# Why Permission denied while using exec command(while writing to the log file )?

Tags: php, exec, permission-denied, logfile

In my local machine I am used exec command as below :

```
 if($serverHost == "api.frapi") 
 {
     $phpBianryPath='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php';
 }
 else
 {
     $phpBianryPath='/usr/bin/php';
 }

 $logDir= dirname(__FILE__). '/BackgroundTask';                
 exec("$phpBianryPath $logDir/notificationCall.php $token >> $logDir/log_file.log 2>&1 &");
```

It works perfect in my local machine.But when I upload it on production server and then try to use it then it gives error as below:

```
sh: /var/www/html/example/src/frapi/custom/Action/BackgroundTask/log_file.log:
Permission denied
```

Please Guide me on this.I don't understand why it is not working in production?

Comment: who is running the script? add a `passthru('whoami');` to the script called using `exec`. What are that users rights (to what groups does he belong, find out using the `groups` command), then check who the oner of the log file is (`ls -lta` in that dir)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem : what do you mean by "add a passthru('whoami'); to the script called using exec"? How to add passthru to exec?

Comment: You're executing a php script, using `exec`, in that script, add an exec or passthru or whatever, and check what the executing user is... While debugging, check the actual output

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem : I checked it. output of whoami is root.output of ls -lta of that file is -rwxrw-r--.Now?

Comment: Running as root? don't... that's dangerous. Not sure if that's even possible. Try `chmod 766 log_file.log`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have the necessary rights to execute that file.
If the server you're running the script has linux use the chmod command to change file permissions.

```
chmod 0764 /var/www/html/example/src/frapi/custom/Action/BackgroundTask/log_file.log
```

4 = read;

2 = write;

1 = execute;

read+write+execute = 4+2+1 = 7;

764 means rwx for owner, rx for group, r for others.

For further documentation please refer to: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: Maybe the user that executes the script is not the owner. Try setting the permission to 0777 for test only and then lower them to your requirements. Also keep in mind when you are setting the permissions to use sudo command, i.e., sudo chmod ...

Comment: I believe there is no need of sudo. By changing permission to 0777,it works.And reduced permission to 0666 It also works.(Original permission is 0664). Is there any disadvantage of changing permission to 0666 from 0664? Thanks

Comment: Increasing the file permissions results in increasing the risk of succeeding attacks. So you'll want to keep them at a minimum. It also depends on what files you give access to. It is important for files with sensitive information to have low permissions. You basically gave permission of executing that file to any user. So it's up to you to analyse if there is a way someone can use this to your disadvantage (this if they can get to it in the first place).

Comment: There is no importance of that file because I am printing only output(error log) statements to that file.Never mind.Thanks.